# How to retain text in textfields in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, textfieldstyle

If there are multiple textfields in a screen in flutter which are edited to suitable text and from that screen when the user moves to other screen and comes back to the same screen where the text fields are. How should I make sure that those textfields have the same text which was entered in the fields and not removed in the screen.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Enter a search term'
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the input text in a variable so if you return to that screen either it will retain state or you can rebuild but since you have the text stored in a variable you will be able to still show that to user. Use `TextEditingController` and set its `text` property accordingly
For Example,

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Then

```
_controller.text = <variable>
```

Take a look at this [post](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

Comment: If your initial page doesn’t rebuild the controller should still preserve it’s value. If it does rebuild then I would vouch for this answer

Comment: @VLXU Thanks for the sugestion, Now I need to implement the similar thing in another context, please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827363/how-to-save-values-from-popup-window-into-an-instance-to-other-class

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TextEditingController` to your `TextField` and call `controller.clear()` only after pushing the other page.

This can be done either by using `await` inside the `onPressed` function or you can use the `.then()` callback if you want you avoid making your `onPressed' function` async`.

Example -

```
//Initialize a controller inside your State class
TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

//Set the _controller on your both TextFields
TextField(
  controller: _controller1,
  //Rest of your code
)

TextField(
  controller: _controller2,
  //Rest of your code
)

//Values Remain Same after pushing the new page with this
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => NextPage()
   ))
}

//Clear the controller after pushing the new page with this
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => NextPage()
   )).then((value) {
      //This makes sure the textfield is cleared after page is pushed.
      _controller1.clear();
      _controller2.clear();
   });
}
```

Comment: I think the question is trying to retain and not remove the value. The questions is seeking to retain the value after a push and subsequent pop

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani thanks for the response, now the similar thing I want to implement in this scenario , I request you to please take a look at this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827363/how-to-save-values-from-popup-window-into-an-instance-to-other-class